# Is there any flutter face authentication API

Tags: flutter, face-recognition, identification

I need to write an application that uses a image from the camera a and recognizes the person's face in order to identify this particular image. 
There are several faces recognition solutions, but I see no solution for face identification.

Does anyone know any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Although I can't find a guide directly for Flutter, you can use the guide for Android for Facial Recognition: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces and the Flutter package for the Firebase Machine Learning Kit: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/detect-faces and build from there.